# How do I route specific paths using WSGIApplication()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, httpwebrequest

Currently I have foo.com/bar routing to a request handler Main.  I also want foo.com/bar/id to route to that request handler (where "id" is an id of an object).

Here's what I tried but it's failing:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/bar', MainHandler),
                                     (r'/bar/(.*)', MainHandler)],
                                     debug=True)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the signature of your `MainHandler.get` method, like so:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, bar_id=None):
        if bar_id is None:
            # Handle /bar requests
        else:
            # Handle /bar/whatever requests
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I don't really understand why I need the var in this case.  Is it because I'm using a regular expression?

Comment: By using that regex, you're telling AppEngine that you want to capture that part of the URL and provide it to your `get()` handler as a parameter.

Comment: @Will Merydith, see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html